# present continuous for temporary state

Tags: present-continuous

> There are some works on my road and internet is not working until next week.

Can I use present continuous as it is temporary state or is it better to use present simple (I don't think so) and say I am not having an internet connection till next week.

Comment: How would you construct the sentence that you have in mind?

Comment: As the one I wrote in the beginning of my question because at the time of speaking internet has already been cut so continuous form should be good  and even if the cut and the work are  going to begin in three weeks it has been planned before so present continuous   should be   fine  .

Answer (score 1):

A native speaker is likely to say something like this:

> Because of roadworks I will not have internet access until (some time) next week.

It would NOT be idiomatic to use **until** after the present continuous: as in: **I am not having (internet access) until.....**

and we generally do NOT use the present continuous in the context of NOT HAVING SOMETHING except with expressions about abstract concepts such as: **I'm not having a good time** or **I'm not having much luck**.

We wouldn't say **I'm not having any pets** or **I'm not having any siblings**. Here we prefer **I don't have**.

Other options are:

> I won't have / I will be without ....internet access until...

In short, the present continuous tense does not work in the context you describe.